Full Text Search with Microsoft SQL Server
I am wondering how I can integrate Wagtail with Microsoft SQL Server. The basic search is working fine, but I would like to perform full text search on custom content.
Basic search endpoint (from default Wagtail) project

def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get("query", None)
    page = request.GET.get("page", 1)

    # Search
    if search_query:
        search_results = list(Page.objects.live().search(search_query))

    else:
        search_results = Page.objects.none()

    # Pagination
    paginator = Paginator(search_results, 10)
    try:
        search_results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        search_results = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        search_results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return TemplateResponse(
        request,
        "search/search.html",
        {
            "search_query": search_query,
            "search_results": search_results,
        },
    )

After investigation I have come to the conclusion that
https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/2c6ab32d61c4215607369ff2e3a13d270c467693/wagtail/search/backends/database/fallback.py#L22
We are using the fallback and Wagtail will not index our content because of our database driver. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to either customize the search logic to search custom fields, or work arounds for the indexing issue in wagtail?

For the time being, we are using an external elasticsearch instance hosted on bonsai to generate the text search, but still seems like a suboptimal solution to me
